# Use GSON to parse json objects into java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a json object with this format:

```
{
    'result': (json array or json object) ,
}
```

The code I am using to parse the json string is:

```
Map<String, Object> responseMap = new Gson().fromJson(
    json,
    new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
);
```

When the result field is a JSON object checking with the following line of code returns "LinkedTreeMap"

```
// returns "LinkedTreeMap"
responseMap.get("result").getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Likewise, all nested JSON objects are parsed into com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap. Is there a way to make GSON parse JSON objects into java.util.HashMap by default instead of com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.

The usual way to solve this problem seems to be to write a class that defines the structure I'd expect to see in the response JSON object. However, the value contained in the 'result' field can be a JSON object or a JSON array, and I do not have a standard format for the expected return objects and what they may contain.

Comment: Does it matter? A TreeMap is just like a HashMap, just has order. For nearly all standard usage, it's fine to use a TreeMap it's just not neccessary

Comment: This isn't a problem that is preventing any progress on my end. I'm just interested in seeing if it's possible to do this in order to use the java standard library instead of importing com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap everywhere I need to access the returned values.

Comment: Why care about the type of map? Simply having 'Map' imported and pulling that should get you what you need, no extra imports required (`Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)responseMap.get("result"); String thing = (String)result.get("thing")`)

Comment: Please add more JSON content to understand the question.

Comment: Additionally to what @josh.trow wrote, you should not import `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` because as the package name suggests, it is a Gson implementation detail and can change or be removed at any point.